# spring integration industry usage

Tags: spring-integration, messaging

I am evaluating options for a new messaging system. I have been looking at spring integration, mulesoft and camel. Key to any framework is it's industry footprint and support. I haven't been able to find any good indication of the spring integration module being used widely and searches return blogs and the like from the early 2010s not more recent.

Does spring integration have a significant industry footprint?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[This survey](https://dzone.com/guides/enterprise-integration-3) is a few years old. The framework is still very actively developed and used. One gauge of that would be to look at the question history here. We get several tens of questions per month.

It now has a popular Java DSL and no longer requires XML configuration (although that is still supported for those who prefer it).

Disclaimer: I am a previous project lead and still a committer, but the DZone survey was independent.

Comment: Thanks for this. After further reading I like the look of the Spring messaging options. I am looking at Spring Cloud Stream, however due to  intenal company policies Kafka the other main messaging brokers supported are not available as an option. I have seen there are some community IBM MQ bindings projects. Would the IBM MQ  option be strategic or does it carry compatibility and supportability risk?  Given my broker limitations would the less opinionated more open and flexible Spring Integration be the better option?

Comment: Hi, @DaleFripp! A few years ago, we had a financial customer who has needed a JMS-spec based binder implementations. They have ended up also developing a few [implementations](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-jms#provided-implementations) of the Spring Cloud Stream's JMS spec; of which, IBM MQ implementation is one. However, they are not actively maintained by the community or the customer – they are a few years behind the current state of upstream Spring Cloud Stream's releases.

Comment: Recently, also, we tried to had it over to the IBM MQ core-development team at IBM, but they weren't keen on taking it up or maintaining and supporting it.

Comment: @DaleFripp - you can get much of the SCSt functionality using `spring-integration-jms`, which sits on top of `spring-jms` (which sits on top of JMS). But you won't get as many opinionated defaults, auto-configuration, etc. But, given the state of the MQ binder, it would seem to be a better option at this time. However, given that SCSt uses Spring Integration underneath; it wouldn't take much heavy lifting to move to it, if he binder situation improves. You would get some auto-configuration if you use it in a Spring Boot application.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all your help. I have one more question if I may. My company makes extensive use of a broker called AMPS (https://www.crankuptheamps.com/). I can see that I could bridge to this as an endpoint relatively easily using their Java API. But could I  use it for my internal Spring Integration flow queues (pub/sub)? I can't see how I would integrate it and keep all the framework benefits like transaction management that I get for free with Spring Integration with JMS.